# How to remove files pertaining to certain scope from directory search

Tags: webstorm, jetbrains-ide

I'm using `Find in path` feature. I've configured a scope which excludes test files. How can I run the search with this files excluded? It seems that at the moment the search can be run either in the selected directory or using scope. Can't both be combined?

Comment: Nope. As you can clearly see from the actual dialog layout, those 2 are exclusive options (or this or that). I do not know what your custom scope is.. but if it's based on file extensions only .. then you can use `!` in "File Masks" to negate the condition. If your scope uses folder names .. then there is no much you can do here: either create another scope just for this search .. or search all folders and then just exclude/delete unwanted locations from Search Results window.

Comment: Thanks, yeah it's based on part of file name, here is the pattern `!file:*.test.*`. I didn't understand about file masks, can you please tell me if it's something that fits my case and how I can go about configuring it?

Comment: No -- in "File Masks" field of "Find in Files" dialog the pattern should be different -- have a look at comments in https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-152091

Comment: @LazyOne, thanks, how do I combine it with the directory path specified there like `D:\server\common\serverj\arsystem\projects\rx\standardlib` ?

Comment: Use both fields at the same time? "File masks" is a check box .. so can be used in addition to the scope (a specific directory in your case)

Comment: @LazyOne, I see, thanks. I've composed the pattern like that `!*.test.js` to exclude file with names like `designer-inspector.directive.test.js` but it finds no files. If I remove `!` from the pattern, it finds only files that are test files. Unchecking `File mask` finds 4 files. Can you help me understand the problem?

Comment: Try with `*.*, !*.test.js` as per comments in that ticket (no idea what IDE version you are using and in what version they have fixed that)

Comment: @LazyOne, thanks, but I doesn't work :(. I'm using Webstorm11, build WS-143.1559 built on December 23, 2015

Comment: It's implemented in 2016.1 only.. -- I thought you were using it already.

Comment: I see, thanks a lot for your help